# Can INSTR() in MySQL benefit from an index?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, database-design, full-text-search

I have a user table that looks something like this for testing:

```
USER
----------------------------------
id   username           name
1    "djangoIsAwesome"  "Ale"
2    "craze123"         "John"
3    "hope this works"  "JJ"
4    "Rage"             "Ludo"
5    "coolguy1996"      "Frank"
```

I need to execute extremely performant queries that respond as someone is typing a search for a user. Normally one would use the LIKE %string% strategy but I can not afford to here as the USER table has millions of rows.

I created a Fulltext index on (username, name) but it seems that Fulltext indices do not support *substring* queries.

**It seems my last resort is to use INSTR(). Would any kind of column index benefit the INSTR() function?**

Example queries:

"J", "wesome", "96", "k"

Comment: *"J", "96", "k"* - too short (see `innodb_ft_min_token_size` variable). *"wesome"* Fulltext does not search for substrings.

Comment: @Akina Is there any other feature in MySQL other than LIKE %string% that searches for substrings?

Comment: INSTR() and LOCATE() functions.

Comment: @Akina does any combination column index benefit a INSTR or LOCATE query?

Comment: None index may improve substring search at all. Except the search from the beginning of the value strictly.

Comment: Am I missing something? How are applications such as Instagram, which uses postgres, able to search for username substrings within milliseconds?

Comment: Do you know that MySQL and PostgreSQL are not the same? Why do you decide that Instagram uses built-in PostgerSQL's fulltext searching tools?

Comment: PS. Fast substring search must use suffix tree method or some another one which is NOT implemented in MySQL (but you may do it "by hands" if needed really).

Comment: @Akina Hmm, I suppose I can get away with LIKE string% searches. These benefit from a standard column index correct?

Comment: `LIKE 'string%'` (without leading `%`) uses index.

Comment: Look for the term "ngram".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of functions and operators almost always precludes the use of indexes.  `INSTR()` is definitely in that category.  `LIKE` with a constant pattern and no wildcards at the beginning of the pattern is an exception.

If you need to handle such scenarios, you might investigate other databases (notably Postgres) that have a wider range of indexing capabilities -- including indexes that can help for partial string matches.

You can also implement something similar in MySQL by using n-grams.  However, this would require a separate data structure and a bit of complication.

You may also be able to implement this using a full text index -- but munging the data on input.  For instance, you might extract adjacent three letter combinations and add them to the index, so:

```
'Frank' --> 'Frank Fra ran ank'
```

Comment: Interesting solution, I'll give it a try.